# Windows 10, Android Studio 2.3.3. Change location AVDs

Tags: android-studio

Windows 10, Android Studio 2.3.3.

I create Emulator. As result it store on

```
"c:\Users\Alex\\.android\avd\"
```

But I want to store AVDs to the different location (e.g. `d:\Programs\Android\AVDs`)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your Environment Variables settings (File Explorer -> Right-click This PC, and open up Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables...), and then add a new **User Variable** of **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** with your directory path as the value which will then automatically add the .android directory from there.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: For anyone reading this I also had to go to `Tools` > `Android` > `SDK Manager` and click on `Edit` to update the location of the Android SDK. It did a scan and found the new location. (Android Studio 3.0.1)