# How to install Android Studio (Giraffe 2022.3) on lab environment (Windows 10) where users have limited space and no admin rights

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I researched before posting, but similar questions are very old and/or target different operating systems.  I found some useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530171/how-to-install-android-studio-on-windows-10-completely-on-a-drive-other-than-the) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501164/windows-10-android-studio-2-3-3-change-location-avds).  However, I think that what I will describe must be a common problem, so this question will hopefully gather some insightful answers and serve as a guideline.

**TL;DR:**

*Need some help on efficiently installing Android Studio (Giraffe 2022.3) on a Lab environment with Windows 10 PCs with pretty small SSDs and second mechanical drives - users won't be able to run updates.*

**The problem - long version**

I am creating an image that will be uploaded to 40-50 PCs that we use in a school lab.  PCs are running Windows 10, and have a fairly limited primary SSD disk (C) and a spatious second mechanical drive (D).  Users have very limited space on C drive (profiles) and obviously no admin rights (cannot install software).  They are allowed to store data on local drive D.

I want to install Android Studio (Giraffe 2022.3) in such a way so that critical components are in C drive and it runs as efficiently as possible.  However, I would like to store big files/directories in D drive if that does not hinder the performance too much.  I guess emulator images can be stored there (I would like to have one or two, maximum, emulators available).

Also, users obviously will not be able to run updates on the software.  Should they just ignore that? Is there another clever way of dealing with updates? Images can only be uploaded once a year on the lab.

Obviously different users use the labs, however we can ask the same users to sit on the same PCs during the courses that involve Android Studio - in case that helps on some decisions during installation (maybe some nesessary downloading per user on D drive that can happen only once, during first time use).

I hope this all makes some sense, and someone has faced a similar problem and could shed some information. Android Studio is quite a complicated piece of software, and the specific restrictions on a public lab make it quite difficult to use efficiently.

Thanks for your time,

thomas